# How to find the largest delta?

Tags: real-analysis

Find the largest positive real number $\delta$ such that, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, we have:
$| \cos x - \cos y| < \sqrt 2$
whenever $|x - y| < \delta.$

In this  [youtube video](https://youtu.be/X8jWRDTQQxc), the  answer is given largest positive real number $\delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

$|\cos x- \cos y| \le  2 |\frac{ \sin(x-y)}{2}| <\sqrt 2\implies 2. \delta=\sqrt 2 \implies \delta=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Is it correct ?

Comment: I haven't looked into this question myself, but it was asked recently here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229749/finding-delta-based-on-given-value-of-epsilon. The answers there are different to yours, so it may be worth taking a look to verify,

Comment: thanx u @user2628206

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding $\delta$ based on given value of $\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229749/finding-delta-based-on-given-value-of-epsilon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too underestimate. You can see using Mean value theorem that $\delta\ge \sqrt{2}$, in fact
$$
|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|\le \sup_{t\in [x,y]}|\sin(t)||x-y|\le|x-y|<\sqrt{2}.
$$

We will use the expression :
$$
\left|\int_x^y\sin(t)dt\right|=|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|
$$
So to maximize the difference $|\cos(x)-\cos(y)|$, we will maximize the area of the function $\sin$ between $x$ and $y$ for every "Shift" of thus bounds.

A careful look to the graph of the function $\sin$, gives that the maximum of the area will be in a symmetric region centred on $\frac\pi2$, which represent the maximum of the function.

So the problem is to find a positive number $a$ such that :
$$
\int_{\pi/2}^{a+\pi/2}\sin(t)dt=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}.
$$
(the number $a$ represent $\delta/2$)
Hence :
$$
\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\int_{\pi/2}^{a+\pi/2}\sin(t)dt=\left[-\cos(t)\right]_{\pi/2}^{a+\pi/2}=\cos(a+\pi/2)=\sin(a).
$$
Finally :
$$
\delta=2a=2\frac\pi4=\frac\pi2
$$